# How to disable an input field according to another selected field value from "combo list " using Python/PySimpleGUI?

Tags: events, config, field, pysimplegui, disable

Dears,

How to disable a input field according to another select field value Python/PySimpleGUI.
Here's the aim of this script : Once an Entry is selected from first "Combo list", it will disable the corresponding entery , either the 2nd or 3rd or both , below is an attempt for my script to achieve that, Unfortunately need additional adjustement in events loop to make it happen. Could you please support on that :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

 layout = [

[sg.Text('Filed 1:', size=(15,1)), sg.Combo(['DisableField2', 'DisableField3', 
'DisableField2&3'], size=(25, 1), key='FIELD1')],
[sg.Text('Field 2:', size=(15,1)), sg.Input(key='FIELD2', size=(25,1))],
[sg.Text('Field 3:', size=(15,1)), sg.Input(key='FIELD3', size=(25,1))],
],

window = sg.Window('MAIN',  layout, finalize=True,element_justification='c')


while True:
event, values = window.read()
print(event, values)

if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
    break

elif event == 'FIELD1':
    window['FIELD1'].update(result2.upper())
    if event == 'DisableField2':
        window['FIELD2'].update(disabled=True)
    elif event == 'DisableField3':
        window['FIELD3'].update(disabled=True)
    elif event == 'DisableField2&3':
        window['FIELD2'].update(disabled=True)
        window['FIELD2'].update(disabled=True)
window.close()
```

Comment: Dear @KillerRebooted, Could you please take a look on this topic? Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrong element configured. Try `window['FIELD2'].update(disabled=True)`  for Input element with key 'FIELD2'.

Comment: Hello @Jason Yan, I chnaged corresponding lines as per the above unfortunately enteries didn't becomes disabled.

Comment: Refer following answer for your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jason Yang for your good clarificatiosn, we're leaning lot things day by day. Please tell me how can I distinguish those disabled fields by adding diffrent color, let's say "Gray".

Comment: Set option `disabled_readonly_background_color="Gray"` of `Input` element in your layout, upgrade your PySimpleGUI from GitHub if this option is not available.

Comment: YES, I miss that, I'm still newbie , It's working fine....one last thing before we finialize this topic : once we select DisableField3, we should have DisableField2 not disabled, which not the case here and when we select both the windows closes

Comment: Add one more statement to set `FIELD2` update with option `disabled=False`, I believe you can add the code for it.

Comment: Excellent @Jason Yang, Works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With method `update(disabled=True)` of element to disable element.

The event will be the key `'FILED1'` of the Combo element when `enable_events=True`.

The decision for which element to be disabled is by the value of Combo element, `values['FIELD1']`, not by the event.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

settings = ['DisableField2', 'DisableField3', 'DisableField2&3']

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Filed 1:'), sg.Combo(settings, size=10, expand_x=True, enable_events=True, key='FIELD1')],
    [sg.Text('Field 2:'), sg.Input(key='FIELD2', size=25, disabled_readonly_background_color="Gray")],
    [sg.Text('Field 3:'), sg.Input(key='FIELD3', size=25, disabled_readonly_background_color="Gray")],
]
window = sg.Window('MAIN',  layout, finalize=True, element_justification='c')

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    print(event, values)

    if event == 'FIELD1':
        setting = values[event]
        if setting == 'DisableField2':
            window['FIELD2'].update(disabled=True)
            window['FIELD3'].update(disabled=False)
        elif setting == 'DisableField3':
            window['FIELD2'].update(disabled=False)
            window['FIELD3'].update(disabled=True)
        elif setting == 'DisableField2&3':
            window['FIELD2'].update(disabled=True)
            window['FIELD3'].update(disabled=True)

window.close()
```

Comment: One last thing before we finialize this topic : once we select DisableField3, we should have DisableField2 not disabled, which not the case here and when we select both the windows closes

Comment: Code updated as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jason Yang for your support